# Why i get "Hello" all the time and not the other messages ? what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs, expo

Why I get "Hello" all the time ? i want to get the other messages ..
what is wrong in my case ?

```
getGreetingTime = (currentTime) => {
    if (!currentTime || !currentTime.isValid()) { return 'Hello'; }

    const splitAfternoon = 12; // 24hr time to split the afternoon
    const splitEvening = 17; // 24hr time to split the evening
    const currentHour = parseFloat(currentTime.format('HH'));

    if (currentHour >= splitAfternoon && currentHour <= splitEvening) {
      // Between 12 PM and 5PM
      return 'Good afternoon';
    } else if (currentHour >= splitEvening) {
      // Between 5PM and Midnight
      return 'Good evening';
    }
    // Between dawn and noon
    return 'Good morning';
  }
```

Comment: because your first if condition is always true and the function returns

Comment: are you passing a value, when getGreetingTime  func is called?

Comment: what is your `currentTime` ?

Comment: 11 am if its help

Comment: is `currentTime` a `moment` object? `11 am` is not a valid value for moment

Comment: @zibi - Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lj43dfqb/ - This is working when the value passed in includes a valid value for moment

Answer (score 0):

Thats the case if your if `(!currentTime || !currentTime.isValid())` condition evaluates to true then  `{ return 'Hello'; }` is executed and once return statemnt is executed it moves out from the current function. So kindly check your `currentTime` what is sent.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubt

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (!currentTime && !currentTime.isValid()) { return 'Hello'; }
```

or

```
if (currentTime == undefined && !currentTime.isValid()) { return 'Hello'; }
```

Comment: If the `currentTime` is `undefined`, your approach will result in an error such as "Cannot read property 'isValid' of undefined"

Comment: In that case, the condition should be as follows.
`if (!(currentTime && currentTime.isValid()))`. But it won't make a difference to the outcome of the function.